# My jQuery variable to PHP is empty when read

Tags: php, jquery, apache

I have an HTML slider called `myRange` that represents years. I want to get the value and print it in this field when I click a button:

```
<div id="test">HELLO</div>
```

I read the value in the script:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

function post()
{
  var year = slider.value
  $.post('year.php', {slideryear:year}, 
  function(data){
    $("#test").html(data);
  });
}
```

And this is the `year.php` file:

```
<?php
    $year = $_POST['slideryear'];
?>
```

When I click the button to show the number in the id="test" paragraph, the paragraph goes blank ("HELLO" disappears). My first attempt with PHP, what am I doing wrong?

I'm running on Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only store the post value in the variable `$year` but you have to give the value back as the response if you want to get it in the callback or else HELLO will be replaced with an empty string.

Try for example:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $year = $_POST['slideryear'];
    echo $year;
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you meant ==, I tried but still nothing shows up, it keeps going blank.

Comment: Are you sure you have a value for slider? What do you see when you run `var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    console.log(slider.value);` Do you see an error in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, the slider gives correct values. I print them in another `<div>` which I haven't included in the post. The console log also shows them when I click the button.

Comment: Can you inspect the asynchronous post call to `year.php` in the network panel? What do you see as the response? And what is the Form Data?

Comment: Here it is:

`year.php | 200 | xhr | jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 | 372 B | 5 ms`

Comment: Ok, I assume you use Chrome? If you click on the filename you get more details and options with tabs. Do you see a response tab or / and a headers tab? There should be more information about the request and the response there. That way you can see the data that is being sent and received. You want to be sure that you send the data to the server and that the server sends a response back with the data.

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome. So the Form Data is, parsed: `slideryear: 1736` and source: `slideryear=1736`

Comment: Ok, when you click on the response tab, do you see a value 1736?

Comment: On response tab of `year.php` I see the whole code that you have posted, everything in between `<?php` `?>`, including the brackets and question marks.

Comment: That seems like the response is the php code itself. Are you sure your php/apache setup is working correctly? I think that if that is working you should get the right result.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I reviewed the installation and it wasn't working properly. Now the variable is read correctly. Thank you for the step-by-step instructions.